# Do I need to share the docker image if I can just share the docker file along with the source code?

Tags: docker, github

I am just starting to learn about docker. Is docker repository (like Docker Hub) useful? I see the docker image as a package of source code and environment configurations (dockerfile) for deploying my application. Well if it's just a package, why can't I just share my source code with the dockerfile (via GitHub for example)? Then the user just downloads it all and uses `docker build` and `docker run`. And there is no need to push the docker image to the repository.

Comment: Ideally that is how it works, docker hub is used to push\pull images. So for e.g if you were to do an app development and want to have database support you don;t want to waste time installing configuraing db stuff for yourself, just pull a Mongo, sqllite, postgres image and get started.
You can also just share you code on git and that should do keeping in mind this is not a custom base image which is local on your laptop\desktop etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two good reasons to prefer pushing an image somewhere:

1. As a downstream user, you can just `docker run` an image from a repository, without additional steps of checking it out or building it.
2. If you're using a compiled language (C, Java, Go, Rust, Haskell, ...) then the image will just contain the compiled artifacts and not the source code.

Think of this like any other software: for most open-source things you can download its source from the Internet and compile it yourself, or you can `apt-get install` or `brew install` a built package using a package manager.

By the same analogy, many open-source things *are* distributed primarily as source code, and people who aren't the primary developer package and redistribute binaries.  In this context, that's the same as adding a `Dockerfile` to the root of your application's GitHub repository, but not publishing an image yourself.  If you don't want to set up a Docker Hub account or CI automation to push built images, but still want to have your source code and instructions to build the image be public, that's a reasonable decision.

Answer (score 0):

That is how it works. You need to put the configuration files in your code, i.e,
`Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.